# How would I use cookies from two domains?

Tags: python-3.x, cookies, flask, setcookie

**Hello,**

I'm trying to create my own cross domain authentication platform. I'm having some issues with cookies. I have a master domain (`master.com`) and an app domain (`app.com`).

**Here is the Issue:**

- `app.com` requests a JavaScript file from `master.com`
- The File executes a Jquery Get request to a flask server on `master.com`
- `master.com` sets a 'session' cookie through `Set-Cookie:`
- `app.com` or `master.com` does not have the cookie

**This is my flask server code as current:**

```py
def set_cookie(response,cookies,domain=".app.com",age=3600*48):
   header = ""
   for h in cookies.keys():
       header=header+"{}={}; ".format(h,cookies[h])
   cook = "{}max-age={}; domain={};".format(header,age,domain)
   response.headers["Set-Cookie"] = cook
   return response

set_cookie(resp,{"session-id":"a UUID","session-key":"another UUID"})
```

And this is the request code:

```
$.post("https://master.com/api/endpoint")
```

Any help would be greatly appreciated.
-Sam

Comment: Hello, did you manage to resolve this?